# Bullseye Code Coverage for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, bullseye

Hey I am facing an issue regarding bullseye code coverage with Qt.
In my .pro file I am adding the following:

```
QMAKE_CC           = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/cl\""
QMAKE_CXX          = $$QMAKE_CC
QMAKE_LINK         = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/link\""
```

Then Performing below commands:
Build 
Run
Run qmake
Rebuild

It is not generating test.cov(coverage) file anywhere in the system.I have added Bullseye path in the system environment path variable. Also, in Bullseye application,I have enabled the option for GNU C/C++ and also clicked on the Coverage Build option in tools.Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you have to add the quotes `\"` in the strings?

Comment: Even if I try doin                                                                                         QMAKE_CC           = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/cl"\"                                                           QMAKE_LINK         = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/link"\"                                                        It doesnt work.

Comment: link.exe and cl.exe are the files present in bullseye bin folder

Comment: http://www.bullseye.com/help/tool-qtCreator.html                                                                    Check this link as well

Comment: Open a command line in a temporary (empty) directory. Type `cl` and execute it with `Enter`. What is the output? If the output string contains "BullseyeCoverage" (or something similar) the [interceptor](http://www.bullseye.com/help/build-integration.html) works. Else the interceptor is not configured correctly (maybe the order in the path variable is incorrect).

Comment: I am getting this as output -->>>   BullseyeCoverage Compile C++ 8.9.45 Windows License 3216  error: cannot find compiler cl. PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\BullseyeCoverage\bin;   and other paths

Comment: Issue Solved:

Instead of adding changes in the .pro file to override the variables in qmake.config(internal QT file), Just make direct changes in Qt file itself.

QMAKE_CC = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/gcc"\"
QMAKE_LINK_C = $$QMAKE_CC
QMAKE_CXX = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/g++"\"
QMAKE_LINK = $$QMAKE_CXX

There are high chances of facing some linking issues  if you dont add the above code in the config file of Qt.
NOTE: This was Qt cross-compilation issue which is now fixed by adding the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was solved by submitter and should be closed.

Submitter said the following in the question comments section, instead of writing an answer:

> Issue Solved: Instead of adding changes in the .pro file to override the variables in qmake.config(internal QT file), Just make direct changes in Qt file itself. 
> `QMAKE_CC = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/gcc"\"`
>
> `QMAKE_LINK_C = $$QMAKE_CC` 
> `QMAKE_CXX = "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/BullseyeCoverage/bin/g++"\"` 
> `QMAKE_LINK = $$QMAKE_CXX` 
> There are high chances of facing some linking issues if you dont add the above code in the config file of Qt. 
> NOTE: This was Qt cross-compilation issue which is now fixed by adding the above code.

---

For anyone else having coverage generation issues with Bullseye, be sure to also check their troubleshooting:

- https://www.bullseye.com/help/index-trouble.html
- https://www.bullseye.com/help/trouble-zero.html
- https://www.bullseye.com/help/trouble-empty.html
- https://www.bullseye.com/help/build-integration.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).